# Framer Motion : How to fix {No initial value for "pathLength" can be inferred. Ensure an initial value for "pathLength" is defined on the component}

Tags: reactjs, animation, jsx, framer-motion

The error specified in the title is obtained when using framer motion's pathLength property to animate svg.
Other properties (I tried rotate and opacity) work as expected without any issues.

**What might be the possible issues?**

```
<svg width="84"
     height="84"
     viewBox="0 0 84 84"
     fill="none"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <motion.path
        d=" \\ some path"
        initial={{
            pathLength: 0,
        }}
        animate={{
            pathLength: 1,
        }}  />
</svg>
```

Even if the error goes away, the svg still doesn't animate